# deceptive site ahead error on site, google console detected some urls, how those can be removed

Tags: html, css, wordpress, malware, phishing

please see screen shot, how those detected sample urls can be deleted, there are no such folders (/easym) in directory at all

https://ibb.co/0CpsyHr

Comment: So, if they are not in the directory they are probably in the .htaccess file. But there is no way for anyone to tell since we cannot see the contents of your directory.